# How to change Gmail notification sound

Tags: gmail, notifications, customization, ringtones

How to change Gmail notification sound on iPhone is question a lot of people ask.

So did I.

Comment: I want answer too - that is not good move to this app - today nowhere is good normal email app. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution that works for me and I want to share it with you.

My gmail notification sound has to even wake me up so I need my custom sound that Gmail app doesn't have.

However iOS Mail app allow you to change notification even with your custom sound - how to make your own notification you can find everywhere on the internet.

When you use Gmail in iOS Mail you will find out that you can't get push notification with Gmail unless you have paid plan with Google.

If you want custom notification sound of your Gmail with push notification you have to do this:

> 1. Make email account which iOS Mail can provide with Push notification (iCloud for instance).
> 2. Forward your Gmail to your new email with push (iCloud)
> 3. Change the notification sound in Settings > Notifications > Mail
> 4. You can change the Alert style on None and you can use Gmail app as you did before only with sound notifications from different app.

It's quite easy and it works for me just fine. I do know however, that it won't be ideal solution for everyone.

Comment: Does anyone understand what he's saying? None of this makes sense to me. :/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for many forums and seen many comments said: can't change Gmail app notification sound.
After 1 hour tried and I found the way to change this sound and it works on iOS 7 Jailkbroken (because I did it on my device using iOS 7).

> 1. Connect your device to PC. Using iFunBox open Gmail app folder (User Applications\Gmail\GmailHybrid.app). You will see
>      "notification.waw" file here.
> 2. I used After Effects to compress new audio file (you can try another program) with options:
>
>    - Format: waw
>    - Audio Output: 44.100 kHz, 16bit, Mono, Audio codec: PCM
> 3. Copy new file to your device by iFunBox.
> 4. Open Ifile on the device, remove original file in Gmail app folder. Copy new file to this folder (atencion the file name).
> 5. Respring. NOTE: I tried with many files, but it only works with the duration is: 1~30 seconds.